# Aborting awaited task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

I have `LoadData` method in my FolderViewModel which is called when page (FolderPage) is navigated to. ( I await method presented below on OnNavigatedTo event handler )

```
public async Task LoadData(Folder folderToLoad)
{
    if (folderToLoad != null)
    {
        FolderName = folderToLoad.Name;
        this.Photographies = await this.dataService.Load(folderToLoad);
    }
}
```

If user enter page and leave it immediately LoadData still fetch data until it finish. I'd like to stop the `LoadData` task when I leave this page. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this WPF, ASP.NET, MVC, something else?

Comment: it's WinRT application.

Comment: data.Service.Load supports cancellation?

Comment: uhm dataService is my own implementation (.Load<T>( ) returns Task<ObservableCollection<T>>)- is it possible to code tasks with cancellation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [implement cancellation in your task-based asynchronous pattern (TAP) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Usually, this means you take a `CancellationToken` and pass it on to any other TAP methods that take a cancellation token.

Comment: How about Tasks (for instance SQLite-net library) which doesn't support CancellationToken? Task.Run() could be solution but I guess it will create new thread so I will need locks, dispatcher to ui thread in some cases etc. ( I'm not sure do I completely understand async pattern )

Comment: It's not possible to cancel an uncancelable task (`Task.Run` is not a solution). If SQLite does not support cancellation, then you'll have to just let the command run to completion.